# Relative Amplitude: Current at full brightness

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

What is the relative amplitude of the flow in the filament of a miniature lamp the instant power is applied in comparison with the current at full brightness?

a. High
b. Low
c. The current is the same at all times
d. It depends on the type of lamp

I've learned that the current is the same at all times, given that the resistance around the bulb does not change all throughout. This then would satisfy Ohm's Law. Would you mind correcting me if I am wrong?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistance "around" the bulb may not change, but the same does not apply to the bulb itself.

The resistivity of many materials changes with temperature. This effect is used, for example, in the thermometer probe that lets a multimeter measure temperature. It uses materials like stainless steel, aluminium, nickel chrome, etc.

In an incandescent bulb, the filament resistance increases with temperature. In other words, it's lower when it's cold - for example when it is switched off.

Hence, at switch-on the current will be at maximum value. As soon as the filament heats up, the resistance increases, and the current drops.

Of course, while this only applies to incandescent bulbs, other types may have similar effects. For example, in LED bulbs the AC-DC converter circuit will have an inrush current as capacitors charge up, so they also experience a peak.